Nice proof that $\text{Alt}$ is natural.
There is a pair of functors $T:\text{kVect}\rightarrow \text{kAlg}$ and $\Lambda:\text{kVect}\rightarrow \text{kAlg}^-$ which are left adjoints to the forgetful functors $U$ (forget the multiplication of a k-algebra) and $U\text{Ev}$ (forget the multiplication and the commutative part of a supercommutative k-algebra). I know that I should have a natural transformation $\text{Alt}:T\implies \Lambda$ whose component is the quotient map $\text{Alt}_V = q:T(V)\rightarrow \Lambda(V) = T(V)/I$ where $I$ is the ideal generated by $\langle\{v\otimes v|v\in V\}\rangle $.
How can I prove that this quotient map is natural?
In this case my problem is that the functors $T$ and $\Lambda$ aren't all that explicit. I know that since they're left adjoints, given $f:V\rightarrow W$, I can construct $T(f)$ for example from the unit/universal arrow by taking the linear map $\eta_W\circ f:V\rightarrow U(T(W))$ and using the universal property that $T$ satisfies.
(Bonus: I thought about doing this by proving it for the tensor power and exterior power functors, which I think I can do since I know that the formula for $\text{Alt}$ should be for multilinear maps, and I know that I have a natural isomorphism $\text{Alt}(V^n,W)\cong \text{Hom}(\Lambda^n(V),W)$ but I don't quite understand how to use that to prove what I want because I am shaky on how precisely the functors $\Lambda^n$ and $\Lambda$ relate to one another).
Edit: In response to Qiaochu's comment, here's what I'm envisioning...


You can do it by considering the sequence of forgetful functors from supercommutative $k$-algebras to $k$-algebras to $k$-vector spaces, then using the fact that adjoints compose (in the opposite direction).

Oh! That's even simpler than I was hoping! Also, I think that's an answer.

@QiaochuYuan any chance you want to write this out as an answer? I'm actually confused about it again now because should I be thinking of $\Lambda$ as a functor into supercommutative k-algebras? Then how can I have a natural transformation from a functor into all k-algebras?

shouldn't it be $\mathrm{Alt}:T\Rightarrow \mathrm{Ev}\Lambda$?

Maybe? I guess it either has to be that or I extend the tensor algebra functor to supercommutative algebras using whatever L is. But neither of those seems to resolve my confusion

Here is one way to set things up. We need to work over a field of characteristic $\neq 2$ to make this version of the construction work.
Consider first the category $\text{Alg}_{\mathbb{N}}(k)$ (I don't know good notation for this) of $\mathbb{N}$-graded $k$-algebras, by which I mean sequences $A_0, A_1, \dots $ of $k$-vector spaces indexed by $\mathbb{N}$ together with a family of $k$-bilinear multiplications $m_{ij} : A_i \otimes A_j \to A_{i+j}$ collectively satisfying the usual $k$-algebra axioms (including the existence of an identity in $A_0$ and so on). There is a forgetful functor
$$U_1 : \text{Alg}_{\mathbb{N}}(k) \ni (A_0, A_1, \dots ) \mapsto A_1 \in \text{Vect}$$
sending a graded $k$-algebra to its degree $1$ part (specifying degree $1$ here is important), and it has a left adjoint $V \mapsto T^{\bullet}(V)$ given by taking the tensor algebra, now regarded as a graded algebra where $T^n(V) \cong V^{\otimes n}$ is in degree $n$. We can generalize here by taking a forgetful functor to graded vector spaces instead, and the left adjoint is a graded version of the tensor algebra (as in it takes as input a graded vector space and keeps track of gradings when tensoring), which reduces to the ordinary tensor algebra when given a vector space concentrated in degree $1$, but that's unnecessary for our purposes.
Next, we can consider $\text{scAlg}_{\mathbb{N}}(k)$ (I don't know good notation for this either), the category of supercommutative graded $k$-algebras (not $\mathbb{Z}_2$-graded), meaning that the multiplications $m_{ij}$ satisfy $m_{ij}(a \otimes b) = (-1)^{ij} m_{ji}(b \otimes a)$ (so here the notation implies that $\deg(a) = i, \deg(b) = j$). There is again a forgetful functor
$$sU_1 : \text{scAlg}_{\mathbb{N}}(k) \ni (A_0, A_1, \dots ) \mapsto A_1 \in \text{Vect}$$
sending a supercommutative graded $k$-algebra to its degree $1$ part, and it has a left adjoint $V \mapsto \Lambda^{\bullet}(V)$ given by taking the exterior algebra, now regarded as a graded algebra where $\Lambda^n(V)$ is in degree $n$.
Now we use the fact that adjoints compose. There is a forgetful functor $i : \text{scAlg}_{\mathbb{N}}(k) \to \text{Alg}_{\mathbb{N}}(k)$ which forgets supercommutativity, and $sU_1$ factors through this forgetful functor, giving us a sequence of forgetful functors
$$\text{scAlg}_{\mathbb{N}}(k) \xrightarrow{i} \text{Alg}_{\mathbb{N}}(k) \xrightarrow{U_1} \text{Vect}.$$
Every forgetful functor in this diagram has a left adjoint, and the left adjoints form a sequence going in the other direction
$$\text{Vect} \xrightarrow{T} \text{Alg}_{\mathbb{N}}(k) \xrightarrow{i^L} \text{scAlg}_{\mathbb{N}}(k)$$
where the left adjoint $i^L$ is "superabelianization" and the composite $i^L \circ T$ is the exterior algebra functor $\Lambda$; this is a fancy careful way of saying that the exterior algebra is the "superabelianization" of the tensor algebra, and that's where the natural transformation between them comes from (although strictly speaking, since we've constructed these functors to have different target categories, we also need to compose with the forgetful functor to graded vector spaces or similar). Because we use graded algebras here we break up "superabelianization" into its graded components $V^{\otimes n} \to \Lambda^n(V)$.

Ahh, so literally all I have to do to to get a natural transformation is take $\eta T:T\implies i\Lambda$ where $\eta$ is the unit of adjunction. Then I guess applying $i_L$ is like quotienting by the appropriate ideal and maybe after applying "$U_n$", I should be able to obtain the usual alternatization formulas? I'll give it a try tomorrow and see if it still makes sense...
